# Pandas dataframe, delete rows in between 2 rows that have same values in some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given a panda dataframes, how would i delete all rows that are in between 2 rows that have the same values on 2 specific columns. In my case I have columns `x,y and id`. I would like if a `x-y` pair appears twice in the dataframe to delete all rows that lay in between those 2.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd                      
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,2,1,3,4], 
                    'y':[1,2,3,4,3,3,4],
                   'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
                             ^     ^
```

As you can see the value pair `x=3,y=3` appears twice in the dataframe, once at `id=3`, once at `id=6`.
How could I spot these rows and drop all rows in between?
So that I would get this for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4], 
                    'y':[1,2,3,4],
                   'id':[1,2,3,7]})
```

The dataframe could also be like that, so that there are more "duplicates" as in my next example the 4,2 pair. I want to spot the outer duplicates so that with the deleting the rows in between them, all other twice or more appearing rows are eliminated too. For example:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,1,4,3,4], 
                     'y':[1,2,3,2,3,2,3,4],
                    'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})               
                              ^ ^   ^ ^              
                            out in in out          
 #should become:    
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4], 
                     'y':[1,2,3,4], 
                    'id':[1,2,3,8]})
```

For my example this should cause a kind of loop elimination of the graph that i represent with the dataframe.
How would i implement that?

Comment: In your sample dataset, 1 also duplicate, Why didn't you consider this one? Do you want to remove only between 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

Let's start from creation of your DataFrame (here I omitted the required import):

```
d = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'x': [1,2,3,4,1,4,3,4], 'y': [1,2,3,2,3,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Note that index values are consecutive numbers (from 0), what will be used later.

Then we have to find duplicated rows, marking **all** instances (*keep=False*):

```
dups = df[df.duplicated(subset=['x', 'y'], keep=False)]
```

These duplicates should then be groupped on *x* and *y*:

```
gr = dups.groupby(['x', 'y'])
```

Then, number of group to which belongs particular row should be added
to `df` as e.g. `grpNo` column.

```
df['grpNo'] = gr.ngroup()
```

The next step is to find the first and last index of row, which
were groupped within the first group (with group No == 0) and save them in
`ind1` and  `ind2`.

```
ind1 = df[df['grpNo'] == 0].index[0]
ind2 = df[df['grpNo'] == 0].index[-1]
```

Then we find a list of index values to be deleted:

```
indToDel = df[(df.index > ind1) & (df.index <= ind2)].index
```

To perform actual deletion of rows, we should execute:

```
df.drop(indToDel, inplace=True)
```

And the last step is to delete `grpNo` column, not needed any more.

```
df.drop('grpNo', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
   id  x  y
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  2
2   3  3  3
7   8  4  4
```

So the whole script can be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'x': [1,2,3,4,1,4,3,4], 'y': [1,2,3,2,3,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dups = df[df.duplicated(subset=['x', 'y'], keep=False)]
gr = dups.groupby(['x', 'y'])
df['grpNo'] = gr.ngroup()
ind1 = df[df['grpNo'] == 0].index[0]
ind2 = df[df['grpNo'] == 0].index[-1]
indToDel = df[(df.index > ind1) & (df.index <= ind2)].index
df.drop(indToDel, inplace=True)
df.drop('grpNo', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for both your examples, although not sure if generalizes to all examples you have in mind:

```
df1[df1['x']==df1['y']]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Franco. That works fine with the examples i gave, but actually they could be any integers and not necessarily x is always equal to y. Thanks for the resonse anyway, i appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome! Maybe you could add more info to the question to make it more clear.